# Removing an image preview when file upload is cancelled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I am trying to preview an image before uploading it.To that end, i have an  which will load the picture whenever a user uploads a picture.

By clicking the image that is preview, the user is able to cancel the upload, and the image previewed will disappear.However, if the user has already selected an image, and then click '*cancel*' when choosing a file to upload(because he changed his mind etc), the image that was previously selected will still remain, and will not disappear.

Is there anyway to remove the image that was previewed in this case?

HTML:

```
<input type='file' id='input1'>
<img id='imagepreview1'>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function readURL(input) {        
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();        
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#imagepreview1').prop('src', e.target.result).show();
            }        
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $("#input1").change(function () {
        readURL(this);
        $('#imagepreview1').show();
    });

    $('#imagepreview1').click(function(){        
        $('#input1').replaceWith($('#input1').clone(true));
        $('#imagepreview1').hide();        
    });

});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LCrE4/    <--JSFiddle link if needed

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/74vyw/ is this what you want

Comment: @UDB nope. What i meant was if i clicked"choose file" and selected a file for upload, the picture would appear in #imagepreview1'. Then, if i click "choose file" again and when the pop up appears for me to select a file, and i click cancel, the image preview for the previously selected image is still there even though the upload has been cancelled. Why doesn't the imagepreview disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the *src* of image every time you click ,

```
$("#input1").click(function () {    
    $('#imagepreview1').attr('src','');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/74vyw/1/)

Comment: Except the src attribute is required (and can't be empty) for HTML5 validation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like adding a class to the image if it's been changed, and then either hide it or update its src later:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/LCrE4/3

```
$('#imagepreview1').prop('src', e.target.result).show().addClass('selected');
```

...

```
var orig_src = $('#imagepreview1').prop('src');

$('#imagepreview1').click(function () {    
    $('#input1').replaceWith($('#input1').clone(true));
    $('#imagepreview1').not('.selected').hide();
    $('#imagepreview1.selected').prop('src', orig_src).removeClass('selected');
});
```